# The rendered output contained the source code html itself with angular js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

The rendered output contained the source code html itself with angular js

I don't know how does it happen

[image: inline]

## root page

```
%h1 Root Page
.row.presentation{"ng-app" => "App"}
  %ng-view

= javascript_include_tag 'angular/controllers/welcome'
```

## template (app/assets/templates/departures.html)

```
<div class="panel panel-transparent" ng-controller="departures">
  <div class="panel-title">
    <h3>
      Departures
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-transparent" ng-repeat="departure in departures_lst">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <h5>{{departure.country}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="container-widget">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <ul class="panel quick-menu clearfix">
            <li class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3" ng-repeat="city in departure.cities">
              <a ng-click="get_destinations(city)">
                <i class="fa fa-plane">></i>
                {{city}}
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Angular.js

```
    'use strict';

    var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);


    App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/',
        {
          templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('departures.html') %> ",
          controller: 'departures'
        }
      )
      $routeProvider.when('/depart_from/:city_name',
        {
          templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('promotion_destinations.html') %> ",
          controller: 'destinations'
        }
      )
    }]);

    App.controller("departures", function($scope, $location, $http) {
        $http.get("/promotion.json")
        .success(function (response) {
          $scope.departures_lst = response;
        });
        $scope.get_destinations = function(city_name) {
              return $location.url("/depart_from/" + city_name);
        };
    });

    App.controller("destinations", function($scope, $location, $http) {
        $http.get("/promot4584ion.json")
        .success(function (response) {
          $scope.destinations_lst = response;
        });
    });


    App.controller("exception_ctl", function($scope, $location, $http) {
        console.log("exception_ctl");
    });
```

Comment: It looks like the HTML was escaped on the server - check the rails logs and the network tab to see where

Comment: Has nothing to do with angular doing this. Check data source

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround, that is move the template view into public folder, eg. `public/ng-template/welcome/arrivals.html` instead of putting it under `app/assets/...`

The problem is due to Rails not related to angular.js

However, I still don't know the real root cause.